# Improper showing of picture in CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is the thing, this is the CSS code [for the image in h1](http://jtcollin.com/chapter4/pacific4/index.html)

```
h1 { background-color: #000033; 
 background-image: url(sunset.jpg); 
 background-position: right; 
 background-repeat: no-repeat; 
 padding-left: 20px; 
 height: 72px; 
 color: #FFFFFF; 
 font-family: Georgia, serif; 
 line-height: 200%; 
 margin-bottom: 0; }
```

I am using the same picture sunset.jpg, but my code is

```
h1{
    background-image:url(images/sunset.jpg);
    background-position: right; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:72px; 
    padding-left:20px;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    margin-bottom:0;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    line-height: 200%; 
}
```

I have to use this code

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

I just can't understand, why in the first CSS code, it does not use `background-size:100% 100%;`and still get a perfect h1?

Comment: Go to that link and remove the `background-color` set for the element. You'll see the magic being spoiled.

Comment: Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/c2bLpszc/

Comment: With your change applied: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/c2bLpszc/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, the idea used on that link is to have a `background-color` that would *blend* to the image giving you the impression that's actually a wider image.

When you tried to reproduce the `styles`, you missed this bit, and got it *solved* by adding the `background-size`, which doesn't give you the same final result (it's actually stretching the image to fill the container).

That's the original `CSS`:

```
h1 {
    /* Removed the property below so you see what's missing in your styles */
    /*background-color: #000033;*/
    background-image: url(http://jtcollin.com/chapter4/pacific4/sunset.jpg);
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
    height: 72px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    line-height: 200%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/c2bLpszc/)

Your `CSS`:

```
h1 {
    background-image: url(http://jtcollin.com/chapter4/pacific4/sunset.jpg);
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
    height: 72px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    line-height: 200%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/c2bLpszc/1/)

Comment: This is the perfect answer. You are better than my Professor.

Comment: Appreciate that. I'm glad I could help you.